# Custom title page: All content centered except

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, titles

I am new in Latex and I should make an page title like this :

[image: example]

My problem is how to do that ?
I tried several template : The close one is: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/university-assignment-title-page
but I don't think it is the best way to do that.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: [How to customize my tite page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280) and [Title Creation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) in the wikibook. With links to examples.

Comment: That is well explained. My case looks like "How to make a solid titlepage?" I don't see how to put a right content inside this

Comment: The *solid titlepage* section is for advanced users. It is not about the look of the page, it is about placing stuff and a few font attributes. This is the most basic stuff. Learn how to do that and a title page is the easiest stuff you can do.

Comment: Comparing the linked template an the source it is giving, it seems the template hasn't been upated in a while. I would stay away from templates in general. There is a lot of confusion going on, as a LaTeX template differs from what you (probably) think it does.

Comment: I understand. Templates are sometimes confusing things

Comment: Thanks dude. In your second link, there is a chapter "Integrating the title page". Since I have the .docx template, I could make easier a pdf to integrate it

Comment: You can also have a look at [this](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/jellyfish.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the repository linked to  on the [wikibook page on title creation] has a similar example. Of course fonts and sizes are different, and more importantly the content, but it is a starting point.

The final one side document can be included in the real thesis paper. Custom margins for the title page are much easier to realise that way.

[image: jellyfish]

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/jellyfish.tex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE
    {\bfseries University of Water World\par}
    School of Atlantis\par
    \vspace{4cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Jellyfish -- Who needs them?\par}
    {\small Seriously}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \par
\end{center}
    \hfill\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \normalsize
        a funny thesis paper brought to you by\par
        \textsc{Carlos Pilkerton}\par
        Enjoy reading
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill

    \centering
    \today
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, openany,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{Gillius2}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, eqparbox, moresize}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{TITRE DU MÉMOIRE}
\author{NOM, PRÉNOM}
\predate{\vfill}
\date{Année académique 2016-2017}
\postdate{\clearpage}
%\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\newpage}
\newcommand{\diploma}[1]{\gdef\Dip{#1}}
\newcommand{\Dip}{}%
\diploma{Bachelier(ère) en informatique de}
\newcommand\institution[1]{%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}}

\setlength\droptitle {-26mm}
%
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\centering\sffamily\large \institution{%
\resizebox{\eqboxwidth{IPL}}{!}{Haute École \MakeUppercase{Léonard de Vinci}}\\[0.2ex] %
\eqmakebox[IPL]{\Large\bfseries\lsstyle\MakeUppercase{Institut Paul Lambin}} \\%
Section Informatique\\[3ex]%
Université catholique de Louvain}\vspace{6cm}}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\HUGE\bfseries\lsstyle}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vskip5cm}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
\large Mémoire présenté par\\\bfseries}
\postauthor{\\en vue de l’obtention du diplôme de\\ \Dip\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=3cm, noheadfoot, nomarginpar}
\maketitle
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A backup solution for https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Integrating_the_title_page(suggested by @Johannes_B)